# Getting another table's string via it's id

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have two tables, but since I can't format them here, you can check the table on this [imgur img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0s7a.png)

The wildcard roles includes strings like `department.*` or `blogger.department.*`

I'm trying to create a role/permission inheritance system but i'm stuck on creating a many-to-many relationship

I've tried to use eloquent but since "wildcards" can't be/aren't a model , I can't use eloquent. So I tried to use the DB Facade but I'm not very good with SQL/DB so I've honestly got no clue on how to do this.

Here's what I need

1. Get the role ID (eg: admin = 1)
2. Get all `wildcard_roles` from the table `role_wildcards` by the Role ID
3. Return a collection of all the wildcard strings

**Notes**

It doesn't have to use eloquent, it can use the DB facade

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably because you haven't shown any attempt

Comment: @AndyHolmes I've tried a few things but I'm not sure how to do it with SQL/DB

Comment: Always worth showing what you've tried so that people can get a better understanding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually quite simple after playing around

```
DB::table('role_wildcards')->where('parent_role_id', $this->id)->get();
```

Thought it'd be much more complicated

Answer (score 0):

**First of you create a relationship from role_wildcards to roles**

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\roles','parent_role_id','id');
}
```

**then you use relationship like below**

```
DB::table('role_wildcards')->with('role')->whereParentRoleId($this->id)->get();
```